# Mocking a property call returning MagicMock, not value

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, mocking

I have the following configuration class:

```
class ConfigB(object):
  Id = None

  def __Init__(self, Id):
    self.Id = Id
```

Which is instantiated in the following class and the property printed:

```
from config.ConfigB import ConfigB

class FileRunner(object):
  def runProcess(self, Id)
    cfgB = ConfigB(Id)
    print(cfgB.Id)
```

I have created the following test class to test it, where I am trying to mock both the instantiation and the cfgB.Id property call:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.__init__')
  @mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB.Id')
  def test_methodscalled(self, cfgBId, cfgBInit):


    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgBId.return_value = 17

    cfgBInit.return_value = None

    print(cfgBId)

    fileRunner.runProcess(1)
```

Note the print(cfgBId) statement before fileRunner is called. I get the following output:

```
<MagicMock name='Id' id='157297352'>
<MagicMock name='Id' id='157297352'>
```

For some reason when I set the return value here in the test class:

```
cfgBId.return_value = 17
```

That is not getting called on the line in the FileRunner() class:

```
print(cfgB.Id)
```

What do I need to do to properly get my configuration property to display?

Also note that my 'ConfigB' class instantiation is much more complicated than displayed above which is why I want to patch the instantiation and the call to the Id property.

*Update: I have changed my class as suggested by @mgilson but it is still not working:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('FileRunner.ConfigB')
  def test_methodscalled(self, cfgB):

    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgB.Id = 17

    print(cfgBId)

    fileRunner.runProcess(1)
```

I am now getting the following output from the two print statements:

```
<MagicMock name='ConfigB' id='157793640'>
<MagicMock name='ConfigB().Id' id='157020512'>
```

Any ideas why the above isn't working?

*Solution:

I was able to get it to work after a minor change to the test method that @mgilson suggested:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('FileRunner.ConfigB')
  def test_methodscalled(self, configB):

    fileRunner = FileRunner()

    cfgB = MagicMock()
    cfgB.Id = 17
    #This will return the cfgB MagicMock when `ConfigB(Id)` is called in `FileRunner` class
    configB.return_value = cfgB 

    print(cfgB.Id)

    fileRunner.runProcess(1)

    #To test whether `ConfigB(17)` was called
    configB.assert_called_with(17)
```

I now get the following outputs:

```
<MagicMock name='ConfigB' id='157147936'>
17
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like it would be better to just replace the entire ConfigB object in the `FileRunner` namespace.  Then your test looks something like this:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock imort MagicMock
import mock
from FileRunner import FileRunner

class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('FileRunner.ConfigB')
  def test_methodscalled(self, cfgB):
    fileRunner = FileRunner()
    cfgB.return_value.Id = 17
    fileRunner.runProcess(1)
```

Note that `@mock.patch('FileRunner.ConfigB')` is going to replace the `ConfigB` class in the `FileRunner` namespace with a mock.  You can then configure the mock to do whatever you like -- e.g. have an `Id` that equals 17.

Comment: So I tried to implement that (see my edit on my post), but I am still not getting the correct outputs.

Comment: Acutally @mgilson I was able to get it to work I think I just changed the line in your code from `cfgB.Id = 17` to `cfgB().Id = 17`. The parenthesis changed everything. Does that make sense to you? If you edit your post to include parenthesis I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @EliSquared -- Yeah, that makes sense.  You want to attach the `Id` to the `return_value` of your mock, not the mock itself (my bad).  I've edited the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

To mock Id property, you can patch the class with a Mock instantiated with the property like so:

```
@mock.patch('ConfigB.ConfigB', Mock(Id='17'))
def test_methodscalled(self, cfgB):
    cfgB.return_value.__init__.return_value = None # FWIW, this isn't necessary
```

Comment: So I couldn't get your suggestion to work, but I did find a solution with the help of @mgilson. See my final update.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've had slightly more complicated problem which I solved in similar way by setting `return_value` for mock used in `mock.patch` (shown below).

Your solution can be further refactored to give you more control over used objects by using `mock.patch` as [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) (Ctrl-F "with patch" in linked section) instead as decorator:

```py
class TestFileRunner(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_methodscalled(self):
    id = 17

    with mock.patch('FileRunner.ConfigB', return_value=Mock(Id=id)) as configB:
        FileRunner().runProcess(1)

    configB.assert_called_with(id)
```

## My case: asserting that call was made by using patched object instance.

I wanted to test conditional logging in some class (code examples simplified). Tested module:

```py
# tested_module.py
import logging
from exceptions import CustomExceptionClass

class ClassUnderTest:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    def tested_instance_method(self, arguments):
        ...  # Some more code.
        if 2 in arguments:
            self.logger.exception(CustomExceptionClass(arguments))
        ...  # Some more code.
```

Working tests (after solving the problem):

```py
# test_module.py
from unittest import mock
import tested_module

class TestModule:
    def test_exception_logged(self):
        method_arguments = 1, 2, 3
        logger_mock = mock.Mock()
        tested_class_instance = mock.Mock(logger=logger_mock)
        exception_mock_instance = mock.Mock()

        with mock.patch.object(tested_module, 'CustomExceptionClass',
                               return_value=exception_mock_instance) as exception_mock:
            tested_module.ClassUnderTest.tested_instance_method(tested_class_instance,
                                                                method_arguments)

            logger_mock.exception.assert_called_once()
            self.assertSequenceEqual(logger_mock.exception.call_args_list,
                                     [mock.call(exception_mock_instance)])
            exception_mock.assert_called_once()
            self.assertSequenceEqual(exception_mock.call_args_list,
                                     [mock.call(method_arguments)])
```

The problematic part, before I came up with solution above was this:

```py
# Check below fails.
self.assertSequenceEqual(logger_mock.exception.call_args_list,
                         [mock.call(exception_mock)])  # Wrong object, "()" problem.
```

Then I tried that:

```py
self.assertSequenceEqual(logger_mock.exception.call_args_list,
                         [mock.call(exception_mock())])  # Can't do `exception_mock()` ...
# ... because it was called 2nd time and assertion below will fail.
exception_mock.assert_called_once()
```

The issue was that I had to somehow get that different mock object, which was returned when `exception_mock` was called and without calling `exception_mock` 2nd time. So creating `mock.Mock` instance up front and assigning to `return_value` was the right answer.